# Jasper Report - Unable to file the file: null

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am using [JasperReport 6.1.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/?source=typ_redirect) for creating `PDF` report in `Java`. In JasperReport's standart configuration has some problems. Some characters does not appear after exporting to PDF. For example Ə,İ,Ğ and Ş.

After googling I found that I must add different font. Also JasperReport show this message: **PDF Font name is now deprecated. You should use a font extension when using non-standart font**.

Now I want to add [Windows Comis Sans MS](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1535) for displaying hidden letters in `PDF`. When I added any `*.ttf` to JasperReport I got `Unable to file the file: null`.

How can I fix this peoblem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved the problem but I do not know my solution is exact solution. In IReport I changed `Font name` as `Dejavu Serif` and `Pdf Embedded` checked as `true`. Now I can create report with Ə,İ,Ğ and Ş letters.

Comment: The same error with me when try to install arial.ttf in netbeans IReport plugin this error message appear  "Unable to file the file: null" why?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the bug, copy the font file (for example, arial.ttf) to NetBeans installation folder and rename it to "null".